# WebStorm configure Mocha to accept command line options

Tags: webstorm, nconf

WebStorm Run-'Edit Configuration' is set up to run Mocha test.

The Mocha Javascript test code accepts nconf command line arguments for e.g.
 --user='production'

How can 'Edit Configuration' for Mocha test be set up to accept the nconf command line argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Extra Mocha Options** field for this:

[image]

Works fine for me when using the following code:

```
var nconf = require('nconf');
nconf.argv();

describe("Numbers", function () {
        var foo, json;

        beforeEach(function(){
            foo = nconf.get('foo');
             ...
```